# How do I compute zeros of a function numerically?

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, mathematica

Say I have a function h(x), so that:

g(x) < h(x) < f(x) or f(x) < h(x) < g(x)

How can I find the zeros of h(x) without knowing h(x)? I mean, numerically.

I know h(x) has 3 zeros. But I only know the intervals due to f(x) and g(x) . Is the median of this intervals the best approximation to h(x)=0 ?

By the way, I'm using Wolfram Mathematica.

[image: functions f(x) and g(x)]

[image: graph of the functions, with the area where h(x) may be]

Comment: What exactly do you mean that you do not know $h(x)$? Can you evaluate $h(x)$ as a "black box" given an input, but do not have a closed form for it? Or are you saying that you wish to obtain the "best possible" estimate for the roots of $h$ using only the given bounds and nothing else?

Comment: @Ian I don't know h(x), so I don't know with a lot of precision its zeros. Is there a way of finding it?

Comment: I'm asking what "don't know" means. Do you only know the bound and the number of roots but nothing else? At this level of generality the problem seems quite badly posed.

Comment: @Ian I know f(x),g(x), the bound, the intervals where the zeros of h are. I just don't know with a lot of precision the zeros.

Comment: If that's all you know, then yes, your best guess is the midpoint of these intervals and there's no way to improve this guess. This seems like a really weird situation, though.

Comment: @Ian yes, that's all we know.